# Backpack or bag for southeast asia

Tags: luggage, australia, southeast-asia

i an going to australia for 6 months and then I want to travel for 2 months through southeast asia.

I do not know what luggage or backpack to buy be.

Any advice is welcome.

More precisely, my questions are:

What size (in litres) is a good idea?
40 litres for the two month travel is too small?

For the two month travel, a luggage with wheels will be a bad idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I always use Victorinox, unless I use the Lightspeed bag instead.  But we have to close your question as opinion-based.  Sorry...

Comment: I have noticed that many people who travel longer take smaller bags or backpacks than people who travel shorter. But it takes a few travels before you find the size that suits you best, if you ever do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to developed parts of South East Asia, bring a reasonable amount of clothes and do laundry. Just bring a good 45L backpack. Besides, t-shirts and shorts in Vietnam, Thailand etc are super cheap :-)

Do not bring a suitcase with wheels, it will be very cumbersome.

Comment: A great answer, but can you help us understand which part of the OP's question you are addressing? If any?  Can you add more substance and take the OP's question head-on?  As it stands now, your answer may attract down votes or flags...